# ¿Cómo tener 2 listas desplegables independientes en laravel

Tags: laravel-5

Tengo una formulario llamado depósitos, en el cual quiero colocar 2 listas desplegables independientes, una llamada bancos, y la otra sucursales pero solo logro que funcione la de bancos.

en el controlador tengo lo siguiente:

```
$bancos = [''=>''] + Banco::pluck('banco','id')->all(); 
    $sucursales = [''=>''] + Sucursal::pluck('sucursal','id')->all();
    return view('depositos.create', compact('bancos','sucursales'));
```

pero me genera el siguiente error

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'prueba.sucursals' doesn't exist (SQL: select `sucursal`, `id` from `sucursals`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece que tu error está en el modelo, revisa si tu tabla en la BD se llama Sucursals o Sucursales, justo en una linea parecida a esto:

```
protected $table = "sucursals";
```

Comment: Gracias, eso arreglo mi problema, llevaba 2 días sin poder avanzar en mi proyecto.

Comment: Excelente.. si puedes marcarla como la respuesta que soluciona tu problema buenisimo. Saludos.